# primeng not rendering primeNG's css, being overridden Angular 4.0.1

Tags: primeng, angular

I am able to get the JSON to render but not the styles. I added the css links to the index.html file:

```
 <!-- #CSS Links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/_theme.scss">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/cruze/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/cupertino/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/cupertino/theme.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/darkness/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/flick/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/home/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/kasper/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lightness/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/ludvig/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/pepper-grinder/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/redmond/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/rocket/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/south-street/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/start/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/trontastic/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/voclain/theme.css">
```

However my console gives me a `404` for each link but the path is correct.

In my html file I have:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3 bordered tableScroll boxSize">
    <div class="centerTree">
        <p-tree [value]="files" layout="horizontal"></p-tree>
    </div>
</div>
```

component:

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'office',
    templateUrl: './office.html',
    styleUrls: ['office.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

})
export class OfficeComponent implements OnInit {

 files: TreeNode[];


 ngOnInit() {
        this.nodeService.getFiles().then(files => {
            this.files = [{
                label: 'Root',
                children: files
            }];
        });
    }
```

When I look at the console to see what css is rendering it is the CSS of the templates, not primefaces. I tried to override it but was not successful.

Comment: Primefaces != primeng

Answer (score 0):

Import css inside component ts file

```
import 'primeng/resources/primeng.min.css'
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but that did not work. I tried both in the `@Component`
`import 'import '../../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';` and
`import 'primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';`

Comment: Do you think this could be a webpack issue?

Comment: Inside your component you dont need to give relative path with ../ because it looks inside node_modules folder by default.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you. However it still is not working, it is using bootstrap.min.css when I look in the console.